# On-The-Fly Filtering Of Results

Tags: filter

[image]I would like to submit a small problem of usability to you.

This is a problem with on-the-fly filtering of results.
The constraint is that the user must first see all the results. Then he filters according to the results he needs to see.

https://xwg5qp.axshare.com

- Home (initial state)
  On the right side, all results are displayed.
  On the left side, all filters (toggle buttons) are disabled.
- Results filtering: pages 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and 7.
- Page 7
  All results are displayed. These results are also available at Home.

Is this filtering confusing?

Thank you for your help:)

Comment: It is not clear on your actual question but looking at the image it seems that your problem is that search results are the same without filters and all filters selected. If it is, you should edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Actually, your question is about two states of the filter: (a) filters are off, and (b) filters are on, right? Your solution looks logically aligned. You can find the same behaviour on the bunch of sites, check specifically ecommerce and travelling (hotels, flights) sites which contain a lot of filters.

Answer (score 1):

I would really say I found it a little difficult to grasp initially but eventually got used to it after going through it for a couple of times.

I interacted with the design and would suggest that the filters (label 1, 2, etc) could be as a drop down list just below the pages and would appear only when you click them). This way you can actually have more space to work with asides being a tad less confusing.

Nice work you've done by the way.